# Displaying htmlspecials chars that have ended up in a utf8 database field

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, htmlspecialchars, utf8mb4

I have a utf8mb4 database field which has ended up with htmlspecials such as `&#39;s`

This is from user entered data via a html form. To display this field in laravel blade I use `{{  $profile }}` but that runs through phps htmlspecialschars feature to prevent xss attack (https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade#displaying-data) and so the output I get is `&#39;s`

I know I can display it as unescaped data using `{!! $profile !!}` but since this is user entered data there's a risk anything could get output.

Whats the best way to approach this. Is there a way to clean it up at the database layer without losing or corrupting the data. Or is there a better technique at the presentation layer whilst avoiding XSS risks?

Note this is data from a legacy database.

Any help appreciated.

*** UPDATE ***

I tried using this htmlpurify package: https://github.com/stevebauman/purify
which seems to do the trick similar to using `htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8',true);` e.g:

```
{{ Purify::clean($value) }} or {{ htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8',true) }}
```

However if I have something like the following in the database:

```
 Jobs & Work
```

Then using htmlpurify or htmlspecialchars as in the example above still ends up as:

```
 Jobs &amp; Work
```

Comment: Since it's legacy data, I'd run a script to convert these back to unescaped in the database. Barring that, something like HTML Purifier.

Comment: Just for info do you get same result with this ? `htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8',true);`

Comment: @Dilek see my update post above. I'm still getting `&amp;` for `&`

Comment: @adam78 I see thanks! I had same problem when I set charset to utf8mb4 in my connection, because my database was utf8 or utf8_general_ci and columns were swedish something dont remember. I couldnt find a solution auto convert that characters to my needs, So I deleted all of them manualy in notpad++ and converted all that table and columns into utf8mb4 and then update with edited content, it works fine now. You know the way, I just wanted to share.

Comment: Please provide an example of the text -- both as shown and via HEX(...).

Answer (score 0):

Output as unescaped and then run through Purify seems to fix e.g.:

```
{!! Purify::clean($value) !!}
```

as opposed to :

```
{{ Purify::clean($value) }}
```